# What is the flaw in my stability analysis?

Tags: ode, stability

The ODE $${d^2x\over dt^2}=-kx; k>0$$can be converted in the system of linear equations as
$$\begin{align}
{dx\over dt} & =v\\
{dv\over dt} &= -kx\\
\end{align}$$

Using Euler’s method, given $x_n$ and $y_n$ and for the time step $\Delta t$, the next values can be determined as 
$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
x_{n+1}\\
v_{n+1}\\
\end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&\Delta t\\
-k\Delta t&1
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x_n\\
v_n\\
\end{matrix}\right].$$

Now the absolute value of the (possibly complex) eigenvalues should be less than $1$ for this algorithm to be stable. But the eigenvalues turn out to be $1\pm i\sqrt{k}\Delta t$ whose absolute values are strictly greater than $1$ for any nonzero time-step $\Delta t$.

So the algorithm should not work for any value of $\Delta t$, however small. But clearly, this is not the case as my programs do come up with (an approximate) solution though.

So where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Its hard to tell when you have a pretty obvious typo in the statement. Is your ODE in fact $$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -kx$$. please clarify so we can help.

Comment: Yep, sorry! I’ll edit.

Comment: For future readers: the system is purely oscillatory (imaginary eigenvalues) and conserves its energy. No fixed-step explicit schemes allow for a correct long term solution (they either explode or dissipate). You can write the Hamiltonian and use a sympletic integrator so that the numerical solution respect the energy conservation. More simply, you can use the Crank-Nicolson scheme which has the property that it does not dissipate or amplify pure complex eigenvalues, therefore the oscillation will keep a constant amplitude (but its phase may gradually degrade if the time step is too large).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But clearly, this is not the case as my programs do come up with (an approximate) solution though.

I believe you did not continue the integration until you see that your integration is not convergent and is not bounded.

I could rewrite your system of ODEs as:

$$\dot{x_{1}} = x_{2}$$

$$\dot{x_{2}} = -kx_{1}$$

Or in matrix form:

$$\dot{X} = AX$$

Where: $X = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2}
\end{bmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-k & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

The equilibrium point of your system of ODEs is: $X^{*} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$, but this equilibrium point is unstable cause the real part of eigenvalues of $A$ are not all negative: $\lambda_{1} = i\sqrt{k}$ and $\lambda_{2} = -i\sqrt{k}$. In fact, the real part of eigenvalues are zero for these two eigenvalues. So, the conclusion is: **no matter how you choose a small $\Delta t$, the forward Euler integration will not remain bounded**.

Let's look at your discretization. I could discretize this system of ODEs in matrix form as:

$$X_{n+1} = (I+\Delta t A) X_{n}$$

Where $X_{n+1}$ and $X_{n}$ are $X$ vectors at times $n+1$ and $n$ respectively. The general formula is:

$$X_{n} = (I+\Delta t A)^{n} X_{0}$$

Where $X_{0}$ is initial condition for vector $X$. In order to have a bounded solution, I need to make sure the Frobenius norm of $||I+\Delta t A||_{F} < 1$. But we have:

$$||I+\Delta t A||_{F} = \sqrt{2+(1+k^{2})\Delta t^{2}} > 1$$

Which shows that no matter what you choose for $\Delta t$, if you continue the integration long enough, finally $(I+\Delta t A)^{n}$ will be blown up at some point.

This is the implementation with Python:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 1

deltats = np.linspace(0.01,0.1,5)

A = [[0,1],[-k,0]]
I = [[1,0],[0,1]]

A = np.array(A)
I = np.array(I)

X0 = [0,np.sqrt(k)]

X0 = np.array(X0)

for deltat in deltats:
        x1 = []
        x2 = []
        B = I + deltat * A
        ts = np.linspace(0,100,int(100/deltat))
        for i,t in enumerate(ts):
                C = np.linalg.matrix_power(B,i)
                x1.append(np.matmul(C,X0)[0])
                x2.append(np.matmul(C,X0)[1])

        plt.plot(ts,x1,label=r'$x_{1}$, $\Delta t$ = '+str(deltat))
        #plt.plot(ts,x2,label=r'$x_{2}$, $\Delta t$ = '+str(deltat))

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('X')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

And you see, when we expect the solution of this system of ODEs with initial condition of $X_{0} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
\sqrt{k}
\end{bmatrix}$ to be $X(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\sqrt{k}t) \\
\sqrt{k}\cos(\sqrt{k}t)
\end{bmatrix}$ and clearly the solution should be bounded smaller than 1, but you see it's not bounded when you continue the integration long enough:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This problem has an invariant which is the total energy
$$
E(t) = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2 + k x^2) = \textrm{constant}
$$
As done by AloneProgrammer, write as first order system
$$
\dot{x}_1 = x_2, \qquad \dot{x}_2 = - k x_1
$$
In the phase space $(x_1,x_2)$, the solution must stay on an ellipse whose size is determined by the initial energy.

Applying forward Euler to this, you can show that
$$
E^{n+1} = E^n + \frac{1}{2}k (\Delta t)^2[ k (x_1^n)^2 + (x_2^n)^2] > E^n
$$
no matter what $\Delta t$ you choose. The solution spirals out in phase space.

Using backward Euler, you can show that $E^{n+1} < E^n$ for any $\Delta t$. The solution spirals inward in phase space.

Trapezoidal method would conserve energy, see

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cpraveen/na/blob/master/ode/periodic1.ipynb

For such problems, look for symplectic methods, e.g.

https://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly_geoint/week2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not too familiar with this form of analysis, but it looks to me like the issue is that your $x_{n+1}$ update should be using $v_{n+1}$ rather than $v_n$ but I could be wrong.

Comment: No, in forward-Euler method, as I’ve used, it is as I’ve mentioned.